# Common.Logging Issues

Tags: c#, common.logging

The project I am working on WPF project, and the error it gives me when trying to parse the Main xml file is:

Could not load assembly or file 'Common.Logging'.

I installed the reference to Common.Logging from NuGet, but for version 3.4 rather than the error version of 2.0.0. Is common logging not backward compatible?

Comment: Nothing is backward compatible in ASP.NET unless you add special configuration telling the linker they are the same.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: OK, but I installed Common.Logging 2.0.0.0, and the it still throws an exception that it can't find the Reference.

Comment: You probably need to recycle so the assembly cache gets updated

Comment: do a google search on "recycle worker process"

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It has been over 10 years since I had to do this but I remember it being very hard to get the syntax exactly right -- double check for typos.